# Google Docs: How to change the color of bullets in bulleted lists?

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to make a "sticky" change to the color of the bullet used in bulleted lists? I would like to have a bullet color that is different from the text color, and that persists – at least for a whole list, better yet for the whole document, and ideally as a default across documents or as a style option.

Failing that is there at least an efficient way to change the color for each bullet? So far all I've been able to figure out is to set the color individually on each item in the list and then to go back and change the text color. It gets tedious.

Answer (score 18):

While it's not the perfect solution, I just discovered a way that should be a little less tedious than what you're currently doing.

I just created a quick bulleted list in a brand new Google Doc using the default color (black):

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4
- Item 5

Once the list is complete, if you single click on one of the bullets, then all bullets in that list are selected (only the bullets are selected, not the item text).  You can then change the color of just the bullets, while leaving the text color unchanged.

Comment: That's great! I tried it and it picks up all of the bullets on the page (but it doesn't appear to get ones on any other pages). That's super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out that clicking once on a bullet point will select all bullet points, but clicking a second time on the same bullet point will cause the selection to switch to just that bullet point.  From there one can change the color of just that bullet point without affecting the associated text.